# Phpmailer send mail without SMTP authentication

Tags: php, email, dns, smtp, phpmailer

I am using Phpmailer for sending emails. Initially it was works fine when I am using SMTP by username and password. If I have tried without SMTP authentication then it returned connection timeout error. Here my code is

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;
$mail->setFrom('xxxx@domainname.com', 'First Last');
$mail->addAddress("xxxx@domainname.com", "Recepient Name");
$mail->addReplyTo("xxxx@domainname.com", "Reply");
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Subject Text";
$mail->Body = "<i>Mail body in HTML</i>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
    echo "Message has been sent successfully";
}

?>
```

The returned error is

> SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)

The mail.log file contains

```
host smtp.secureserver.net[68.178.213.203] refused to talk to
me: 554 p3plibsmtp03-06.prod.phx3.secureserver.net bizsmtp
IB105. Connection refused. <ip address> is listed on the
Exploits Block List (XBL)<http://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/ip
address> Please visit http://www.spamhaus.org/xbl/ for
more information.
```

Comment: Have you checked your IP address at www.spamhaus.org as the error message suggests it on a blocked list.

Comment: Yes My ip is listed on the XBL.

Comment: This is obviously on GoDaddy, but it's very strange that they should be blocking their own internal IPs using an external blacklist! I'd suggest asking GoDady about this, as well as seeing what's on spamhaus.

Comment: Now I unlisted my ip from spamhaus. still connection time out error. but there is no log in mail.log file

Answer (score 3):

check your ip is listed on the spamhaus blocklist removal center.

https://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/your-ip-address

If it is listed then unlist them by following their procedures. It takes some time. remove the SMTP configuration from the code.

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->setFrom('xxxx@domainname.com', 'First Last');
$mail->addAddress("xxxx@domainname.com", "Recepient Name");
$mail->addReplyTo("xxxx@domainname.com", "Reply");
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Subject Text";
$mail->Body = "<i>Mail body in HTML</i>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the plain text version of the email content";

if(!$mail->send()) 
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
    echo "Message has been sent successfully";
}

?>
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

//use PHPMAILER to send the mail its working fine and configure the SMTP relay on server properly

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php"; //PHPMailer Object 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                           
$mail->isSMTP();        
$mail->Host = "smtp.xxxxxxx.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;                      
$mail->Port = 25;                    
$mail->From = "xxx@xxxxx.com";
$mail->FromName = "xxxxxxxx";
$mail->addAddress("xxxxx@xxxxxxxx.com", "Recepient Name");
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "Subject is here";
$mail->Body = "Hello, <br>test body ";
if(!$mail->send())
{
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
echo "Message has been sent successfully";
}
```